# Is there any migration document for moving from v2 to v4 clio api?

Tags: migration, documentation, clio-api

Since the v2 clio api is now deprecated, is there any documentation around migrating from v2 to v4 api?

Comment: sorry this is w.r.t to clio api.

Answer (score 0):

I made these quick notes when I was doing my API upgrade. Not sure if they are helpful or not:

```
Clio v4 Path                                    | Clio v2 Path                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
/users.json?enabled=true                        | /users                                     |
/users.json?subscription_type=Attorney          | /users                                     |
/contacts.json?type=Company&client_only=true    | /contacts?matters_status=Open&type=Company |
/contacts/[id].json                             | /contacts/[id]                             |
/matters.json                                   | /matters                                   |
/activities/events.json                         | /timeline_events                           |
/activities.json                                | /activities                                |
/contacts.json (type=Company)                   | /contacts/$clio_id                         |
```